# ngOnDestroy works when open and closing component. Not when leaving website. Angular

Tags: angular

I've a component in my angular app that I would like to handle some information after the user leaves the website/app.

**chat.component.ts**

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.chatService.newUserCount.subscribe(data => {
      this.chatCount = data--;
    });
    this.chatService.removeUser();
    this.chatService.sendMessage('User has left');
    this.chatService.leaveChat('User left');
  }
```

I have a toggle button that shows/hides the above component. When closing the component ngOnDestroy() works and the code executes properly. But, when the user leaves the website, the code does not execute. What am I doing wrong? Am I doing this in the wrong code section?

Comment: you can add `@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])` and execute the code in the `ngOnDesotry` there

Comment: honestly I don't really understand how to implement the syntax for your suggestion. I understand window:beforunload, but I don't know to implement my code inside the @HostListener.. I'm not overly familiar with Javascript annotations

Comment: `@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  sendDataBeforePageLeave() { this.ngOnDestroy(); }` something like this

Comment: :| getting syntax errors. Something about Declaration expected.

Comment: an example with resize event: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ta5usx

Comment: Thank you for that, but I'm still receiving errors. Would it make a difference if  I'm using Angular 6?

Comment: Ahhhhh, yes I see. that makes sense. I was doing it inside a function.

Comment: That worked Jacopo, thank you very much for that. Do you consider this good practice? I'd like to upvote you and your answer since you were first. Or at least accept your answer.

Comment: I personally haven't used once the beforeunload to do something. But in my application I'm using the @HostListener for the window resize and it sorks great. I don't mind the reputation, the answer above is fine tho, you can give him the right answer :)

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In that case, you can not use `ngDestroy`. You will have to use browser default
`unload` and `beforeunload` methods. In angular you can use it with `HostListner`

Try something like this:

```
export class AppComponent  {

  name = 'Angular';
   @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  doSomething() {
  }
    @HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ])
  unloadHandler(event) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This is the working example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cax8jw

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

The answer of @siddharth shah is good but restricts the developer to using the `AppComponent` only for handling the unload event. `@HostListener` does not work in a Service for example.

Here is the solution that allows you to use the `ngOnDestroy` method to handle an `unload` event.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService implements OnDestroy {


constructor(){
   this.startListening();
}

private startListening(): void {
   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.ngOnDestroy.bind(this));
}

private stopListening(): void {
   window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.ngOnDestroy.bind(this));
}

  ngOnDestroy(){

    //your own code here...

    this.stopListening();

  }

}
```